# "Venkat at Axiom Studios Please Help" dose anyone know how i would use gestures in unity3D for Android to track a 2 finger V motion

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, monodevelop, gestures

Ok so here is my question,

I am trying to figure out how I would be able to register that a user has used two fingers to make a V on the screen(finger start point would be where the user touches with there two fingers and then by spreading  there two fingers while moving up to make a V shape) using Unity 3d for android.

I have never done gestures involving shapes before so any advice, links or examples on how I could do this would be greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance 
Graeme

Edited:
so i have been trying to figure this out while waiting for someone to help me out.

this is what I have got so far, it isn't working the way i want it to yet but I am not sure what I'm doing wrong as i have never attempted to do anything like this with gestures before. any help at all would be greatly appreciated

thanks Again
Graeme

```
using UnityEngine;
```

using System.Collections;

public class Pinchv : MonoBehaviour {

```
public Vector2 leftFingerStartPosition;
public Vector2 leftFingerEndPosition;

public Vector2 rightFingerStartPosition;
public Vector2 rightFingerEndPosition;

void Update () {

    foreach(Touch touch in Input.touches)
    {
        if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began){

            Touch leftFinger = Input.GetTouch (0);
            Touch rightFinger = Input.GetTouch (1);

            leftFingerStartPosition = Input.GetTouch (0).position;
            leftFingerEndPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).position;

            rightFingerStartPosition = Input.GetTouch(1).position;
            rightFingerEndPosition = Input.GetTouch(1).position;


            if(Input.touchCount == 2 && Mathf.Abs(leftFingerEndPosition.x + Screen.width - leftFingerStartPosition.x) > 20 &&
               Mathf.Abs(leftFingerEndPosition.y + Screen.height - leftFingerStartPosition.y) > 60){

                if(Input.touchCount == 2 && Mathf.Abs(rightFingerEndPosition.x + Screen.width - rightFingerStartPosition.x) > 20 &&
                   Mathf.Abs(rightFingerEndPosition.y + Screen.height - rightFingerStartPosition.y) > 60){
                    Debug.Log ("its a v ");
                }
            }
            if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended){
                leftFingerStartPosition = Vector2.zero;
                leftFingerEndPosition = Vector2.zero;


                rightFingerStartPosition = Vector2.zero;
                rightFingerEndPosition = Vector2.zero;  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

**EDIT**:

so i took your advice and tried something different  but unfortunately it does not work at all.

I'm about to start pulling my hair out soon if i cant figure this out LOL. here is the new code i tried to create that do not work Can Someone Please help me solve this its been driving me nuts now for 3 days lol.

@Venkat at Axiom Studios could you help me out again it would be greatly appreciated :)

Patiently waiting 
Graeme

```
using UnityEngine;
```

using System.Collections;

public class Pinchv : MonoBehaviour {

```
public Vector2 fingerOneStartPosition;
public Vector2 fingerOneEndPosition;

public Vector2 fingerTwoStartPosition;
public Vector2 fingerTwoEndPosition;

void Update () {

    foreach(Touch touch in Input.touches)
    {
        if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began){

        //  Touch leftFinger = Input.GetTouch (0);
        //  Touch rightFinger = Input.GetTouch (1);

            fingerOneStartPosition = Input.GetTouch (0).position;
            fingerOneEndPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).position;

            fingerTwoStartPosition = Input.GetTouch(1).position;
            fingerTwoEndPosition = Input.GetTouch(1).position;

            if(Input.touchCount == 2 && Mathf.Abs(fingerOneStartPosition.x - fingerOneEndPosition.x) > 700 &&
               Mathf.Abs(fingerOneStartPosition.y - fingerOneEndPosition.y) > 120){
                if(Input.touchCount == 2 && Mathf.Abs(fingerTwoStartPosition.x - fingerTwoEndPosition.x) > 700 &&
                   Mathf.Abs(fingerTwoStartPosition.y - fingerTwoEndPosition.y) > 120){

                    Debug.Log ("its a v ");
                }
            }
        }
            if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended){
                fingerOneStartPosition = fingerOneEndPosition;
                fingerOneEndPosition = Vector2.zero;


                fingerTwoStartPosition = fingerTwoEndPosition;
                fingerTwoEndPosition = Vector2.zero;    
            }
        }
    }

public void OnGUI(){

    GUILayout.Label("Where am i fingerone X : " + fingerOneStartPosition + "end position" + fingerOneEndPosition);
    GUILayout.Label("Where am i fingerone X : " + fingerTwoStartPosition + "end position" + fingerTwoEndPosition);
}
```

}

Comment: well, for one thing, I don't think left/right fingers will always be left=0, right=1 in the touch input list. Perhaps trying something similar while checking for both possibilities would help?

Comment: thanks i didn't notice that :) that will definitely help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Graeme

Ok, I came up with some partly hacky code. It's by no means a fantastic piece of code, but it should give you a rather clear idea of how to approach the problem.

The code does work (tested with a Moto G 1st Gen, Unity 4.6), but it'll still give some incorrect results.
I've commented the portions of the class where I see potential problems, so you can use this as a decent starting point.

Try it out and let me know. There are definitely more elegant solution than this one, in fact I was working on a gesture recog library for Unity a few months ago. I should probably dust it off and finish it :P

**Unity C# code**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class DetectVGesture : MonoBehaviour {

//Note : This was tested on a 1st Gen Moto G (1280 x 720 resolution, IIRC)
// and an orthographic size of 5.
//Why this matters :
//The Vector2 minimumDeltas uses Screen units, so resolution matters here
//The float maxDistBetInitPos uses World units, so if the camera's ortho size is larger, this value becomes larger as well

//Therefore, some trial and error in these values will be needed to get it to work right

//TODO : Write some code to take into account screen resolution and camera size / FOV.
//If anyone feels like editing that portion in, please feel free

//The touches used are maintained in these two lists
private List<Touch> firstTouches = new List<Touch>();
private List<Touch> secondTouches = new List<Touch>();

//This is the minimum distance in SCREEN units 
//of touch.deltaTouch for a new touch in TouchPhase.Moved to register
public Vector2 minimumDeltas = new Vector2(1, 1);

//This is the maximum distance between the two initial touches
//in WORLD units for the algorithm to work
public float maxDistBetInitPos = 3f;

//These are the minimum and maximum angles between the two
//"ARMS" of the "V" for a V gesture to be recognized
public Vector2 vAnglesMinMax = new Vector2(15, 60);


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}


void OnGUI () {


    GUI.Label(new Rect(10, 10, 100, 50), "Touches "+Input.touchCount.ToString());

    if(Input.touchCount > 0)
        GUI.Label(new Rect(110, 10, 100, 50), "Touch1 "+Input.touches[0].position.ToString());

    if(Input.touchCount > 1)
        GUI.Label(new Rect(210, 10, 100, 50), "Touch2 "+Input.touches[1].position.ToString());

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {


    //For this sample, we're only interested in a "V" created with 
    //2 fingers, so we'l ignore the rest
    if(Input.touchCount == 2) {

        foreach(Touch touch in Input.touches) {

            //The below two lines are to allow for an early
            //exit if EITHER of the fingers is stationary. 
            //Uncomment the lines if you want touches to be registered
            //only when BOTH fingers move.
            //if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary)
                //return;

            //This is the first time TWO fingers are registered,
            //so we can use this as our starting point, where the
            //touches are closest to each other. 
            //From here on, I'll refer this to as the BOTTOM of the "V"
            if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
                CheckTouchAndAdd(Input.touches[0], Input.touches[1]);
            }

            //There was some movement, so let's check what it is
            if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {

                //The movement in this touch is at least as much as we want
                //So, we add both the touches, and we move to the next iteration
                //Here, I want both the X & Y delta positions to meet my minimum
                //delta distance. You can change this to either X or Y.
                if(Mathf.Abs(touch.deltaPosition.x) >= minimumDeltas.x &&
                   Mathf.Abs(touch.deltaPosition.y) >= minimumDeltas.y) {
                    CheckTouchAndAdd(Input.touches[0], Input.touches[1]);
                }

                else {
                    Debug.Log("There was too less of delta!");
                }

            }

            //The touch / touches have ended. 
            //So let's clear the lists for the next trial
            if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended) {
                firstTouches.Clear();
                secondTouches.Clear();
            }

        }//Iterate over touches in Input.touches ends
    }//Input.touchCount == 2 ends
}

private void CheckTouchAndAdd (Touch touch1, Touch touch2) {
    if(!firstTouches.Contains(touch1) && !secondTouches.Contains(touch2)) {
        firstTouches.Add(touch1);
        secondTouches.Add(touch2);
        CheckForV();
    }

}


private void CheckForV () {

    if(firstTouches.Count < 5 || secondTouches.Count < 5) {
        Debug.Log("Not enough touches to perform the check! ");
        return;
    }


    //First, let's check if the two initial touch points
    //were relatively close enough to warrant a "V"
    //If they're not, we'll have an early exit
    Vector3 firstTouchInitPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(firstTouches[0].position);
    Vector3 secondTouchInitPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(secondTouches[0].position);

    //First we check if the X distance falls within our limit of maximum distance
    if(Mathf.Abs(secondTouchInitPos.x - firstTouchInitPos.x) > maxDistBetInitPos) {
        Debug.Log (string.Format("The X values were too far apart! Exiting check First {0}," +
                                 "Second {1}, Distance {2}", 
                                 new object[] { firstTouchInitPos.x, secondTouchInitPos.x, 
        Mathf.Abs(secondTouchInitPos.x - firstTouchInitPos.x)} ));
        return;
    }

    //Then we check the same for Y
    if(Mathf.Abs(secondTouchInitPos.y - firstTouchInitPos.y) > maxDistBetInitPos) {
        Debug.Log (string.Format("The Y values were too far apart! Exiting check First {0}," +
                                 "Second {1}, Distance {2}", 
                                 new object[] { firstTouchInitPos.y, secondTouchInitPos.y, 
            Mathf.Abs(secondTouchInitPos.y - firstTouchInitPos.y)} ));
        return;
    }


    //If we reach this point, both the X & the Y positions are within the maximum distance
    //we want. So, they're close enough that we can calculate the average between the two Vectors
    //and assume that both these Vectors intersect at the average point. (i.e. the average point
    //is the corner at the BOTTOM of the "V")

    //Note that there are more elegant ways of doing this. You can always use trignometry to do so
    //but for the sake of this example, this should yield fairly good results.

    Vector3 bottomCornerPoint = new Vector3( (firstTouchInitPos.x + secondTouchInitPos.x) * 0.5f, 
                                            (firstTouchInitPos.y + secondTouchInitPos.y) * 0.5f );


    //Now that we have our bottom point, we then calculate the Vector between this common
    //bottom point, and the last touch point added to each list. From this point
    //I'll refer to these two Vectors as the ARMS of the "V" 
    Vector3 arm1 = new Vector3( firstTouches[firstTouches.Count - 1].position.x - bottomCornerPoint.x,
                               firstTouches[firstTouches.Count - 1].position.y - bottomCornerPoint.y );

    Vector3 arm2 = new Vector3( secondTouches[secondTouches.Count - 1].position.x - bottomCornerPoint.x,
                               secondTouches[secondTouches.Count - 1].position.y - bottomCornerPoint.y );


    //Now let's calculate the angle between the ARMS of the "V".
    //If the angle is too small (< 15 degrees), or too large (> 60 degrees), 
    //it's not really a "V", so we'll exit

    //Note: Vector2.Angle / Vector3.Angle perform a DOT product of the two vectors
    //Therefore in certain cases, you're going to get incorrect results.
    //TODO : If anyone can, please change the below to use a cross product
    //to calculate the angle between the Vectors.


    if(Vector3.Angle(arm1, arm2) < vAnglesMinMax.x ||
       Vector3.Angle(arm1, arm2) > vAnglesMinMax.y) {

        Debug.Log (string.Format("The angle was outside the allowed range! Angle {0}", 
                                 new object[] { Vector3.Angle(arm1, arm2) } ));
        return;
    }

    //If we reach this point, everything's great, we have a "V"!
    Debug.Log ("There's a V gesture here!");
}


}
```

**The logic behind the code**

I've assumed the following

1. The "V" is always drawn with the two fingers starting close together, and move away from each other.
2. When the fingers move away from each other, they move in the same direction in one axis, and in opposite directions in the other axis. (For example, if the "V" is drawn exactly like the letter, then both fingers move in the positive Y axis, and one finger moves towards the negative X axis, and the other towards the positive X axis)
3. The fingers are relatively close together, so the average value of the two points can be used as the point where the two arms of the "V" meet. (Please read the code for an alternative mechanism)

**Lousy attempt at graphically representing my thoughts below**

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much @Venkat this is a great help :)